# Is it possible to use make to remove obsolete targets

Tags: makefile, obsolete

I use make to create thumbnails from image files that will in turn be used to create web pages.

Sometimes I delete a source image and I would like the thumbnail to be removed automatically.  The obvious way to do it would be to simply add a rule where the target and prerequisite are swapped but that causes a circular reference and messages like this:

make[2]: Circular image123.jpg <- thumbnails/image123.jpg dependency dropped.

Is there a way to do it or must I use a separate makefile?  Actually tried but I can't seem to make that work either.  I tried this:

```
# -*- mode: makefile -*-

images = $(wildcard *.jpg) 
thumbnails = $(wildcard thumbnails/*.jpg) 

.PHONY: all
all : $(images)


# Delete thumbnails if source is not present.
%.jpg: thumbnails/%.jpg
    [ -f "$@" ] || rm "$<"
```

It didn't do anything except print one line referring to the image that is to be kept.

To summarize: is there a way to use make to remove targets that would not be built if they were missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's set up a rule to build the thumbnails:

```
images := $(wildcard *.jpg)
TARGETS := $(addprefix thumbnails/, $(images))

.PHONY: all
all : $(TARGETS)

thumbnails/%.jpg: %.jpg
    create the thumbnail somehow
```

Then add some code to find the obsolete thumbnails:

```
thumbnails := $(wildcard thumbnails/*.jpg)
OBSOLETE := $(filter-out $(TARGETS), $(thumbnails))
```

Then write a rule to remove them:

```
.PHONY: purge
purge:
    rm $(OBSOLETE)
```

This will cause trouble if there are no obsolete thumbnails, so let's wrap the recipe in a conditional:

```
purge:
ifneq ($(OBSOLETE),)
    rm $(OBSOLETE)
endif
```

And finally make `purge` a prerequisite of `all`:

```
all : $(TARGETS) purge
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly but I have a question: does the use of := instead of = make any difference?  I tried it with and without the colon and can't see any difference in the behaviour.  Which one should be used by default?

Comment: Read about the difference here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html  In short, in this specific situation the _behavior_ is the same, but the `=` version does more work.  In a small example like this the difference won't be measurable however.